# How to combine imageresizer responsive images with lazy load

Tags: imageresizer

I have implemented a lazy-load solution for images using http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload, and it works as expected.

Now that the DNN skin I'm working on is responsive, I want to make use of ImageResizer's responsive solution: http://imageresizing.net/blog/2013/effortless-responsive-images -- the setup is working right now, but when combined with lazy-load, the images that are served are no longer responsive.

Is there a way to combine these two technologies?

We run the latest .NET and IIS 7+. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Images added to the page after DOMLoaded will not be detected by [Slimmage.js](https://github.com/imazen/slimmage) unless you call `window.slimmage.checkResponsiveImages()` . If you use a separate lazy-load or jQuery plugin that modifies images, call checkResponsiveImages() after it completes its work.

Browser vendors **advise against lazy image loading**, as it drains mobile device power. Turning on the wifi or LTE radio is the most expensive operation for a device, and lazy loading can make it 3-10x more chatty.